# App crash with actionbar

Tags: android-actionbar

i'm new on Android. I'm trying to implent an actionbar im my activity. Everytime i run that, the app crash.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_percorsodisabili);
    //Option Bar
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Percorso Bici");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Resources res = getResources();

    myVist3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myVist3);
    items = res.getStringArray(R.array.nomi_percorsi3);
    descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.desc_percorsi3);
    content = res.getStringArray(R.array.desc_percorsi3);
    ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(percorsodisabili.this, items,foto,descriptions,content);
    myVist3.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "The app crashes" is too vague in almost all cases as a basis for a useful analysis of a software error. Can you please edit the question and include the the error message and/or stack trace or an excerpt of the relevant part of the stack trace if it's very long?

Answer (score 0):

Add the toolbar to your activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <!--YOUR LAYOUT CODE-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then initialize java code for activity:

*Use **android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar** in case you are using **AppCompactActivity***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```